# Shared library not found when compiling a C program

Tags: c, compilation

So, I have a simple program which looks like so:

```
#include <amqp.h>
#include <amqp_framing.h>
int main(int argc, char const * const *argv) {
   amqp_connection_state_t conn;
   conn = amqp_new_connection();
   amqp_destroy_connection(conn);
   return 0;
}
```

This program depends on rabbitmq-c library. I compiled it with no errors. So, when I run

```
$ ls /rabbitmq-c/_install/include/
```

I get all its header files, that I need:

```
amqp.h
amqp_framing.h
amqp_tcp_socket.h
```

And when I run

```
$ ls /rabbitmq-c/_build/librabbitmq/
```

I see all needed ".so" files:

```
CMakeFiles
Makefile
cmake_install.cmake
config.h
librabbitmq.a
librabbitmq.so
librabbitmq.so.4
librabbitmq.so.4.4.1
```

And finally I compile my own program like so:

```
$ gcc -I/rabbitmq-c/_install/include/ -g -Wall -c main.c
$ gcc -L/rabbitmq-c/_build/librabbitmq/ -g -Wall -o rabbit main.o -lrabbitmq
```

It compiles with no errors. However, when I do:

```
$ ldd ./rabbit
```

I get this message:

> librabbitmq.so.4 => not found

So, what am I missing and how can I fix it?

Comment: Were there no instructions on how to install rabbitmq properly so that it is in the system folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you link shared library into an executable, the linker will recorder the library name (in this case `librabbitmq.so.4`) into the executable. It is the job of the dynamic linker (ld.so), to locate the libraries, and combine them for execution.

To locate the libraries, the dynamic linker constructs a search path (similar to PATH). This include:

1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH
2. Hard-coded directories added to the executable.
3. Default folders (/lib, /usr/lib, etc.).

In the above case, looks like neither #1 nor #2 were used, and the library is not in the default location. Can be fixed using #1 or #2

```
# Option 1.
# Both gcc, and ldd consult LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/rabbitmq-c/_build/librabbitmq
gcc -g -Wall -o rabbit main.o -lrabbitmq
ldd ./rabbit

# Option #2
# Inject SO directory into the executable with -Wl,-rpath,...
gcc -L/rabbitmq-c/_build/librabbitmq/ -Wl,-rpath,/rabbitmq-c/_build/librabbitmq/ -g -Wall -o rabbit main.o -lrabbitmq
ldd ./rabbit
```

Consult `man ld.so` for the full details.

From personal experience, when dealing with 'one-off' libraries, better to use the 'rpath' (#2) approach. Trying to add lot of locations into LD_LIBRARY_PATH can easily result in hard to manage, long, LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Using LD_LIBRARY_PATH works best when a wrapper script is created to launch the program

```
File: rabbit-run (same folder as executable)

# Prepend rabbitmq SO location to current LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/rabbitmq-c/_build/librabbitmq${LD_LIBRARY_PATH+:$X}
# Execute the binary, from the same location of the launcher
${0%/*}/./rabbit
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it in a minute!

Answer (score 0):

If your binary don't find your "librabbitmq.so.4", that means this shared object is not found by ld (the dynamic linker)

First step, do a "ldconfig". Does this solve your problem ?
Yes ? Cool.

if not, then you have to tell ldconfig where to look to find "librabbitmq.so.4".
So either you move it in a knowed folder (LD_LIBRARY_PATH for exemple) or add it so it will be knowed by ld.

```
echo '/rabbitmq-c/_build/librabbitmq' > '/etc/ld.so.conf.d/name_this_file_yourself.conf'
ldconfig
```

This should fix your issue.